# Laravel sending mail from different email addresses

Tags: php, laravel-8

So I am working on a CRM using laravel and it has to have a built in mail box. The users emails and passwords on the app are going to be same as for the emails on the IMAP server. My question is should connect to each different email account when sending an Email or can I just connect to the mail server and use the "from" method from laravel when sending an Email like so:

````
    {
        $message->from('username@domain.com', 'full_name');

        $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
    });```
````

Comment: Well why don't you try it and see? There's no obvious reason you can't use a generic "from" address if that's appropriate per your requirements. If you want the recipient to be able to easily reply back to a different address, then add that address in the reply-to field of the email.

Comment: The thing is I still have no access to the server and I haven't tried it before. So that means if I have access to the mail server I can send emails from any adress within the server right? Edit: typo

Comment: It depends on how the mailserver is configured. Some require account-specific authentication, some don't. Speak to the mailserver administrator if you don't know how it's set up or what it requires. Can you send via SMTP, or must you use IMAP? All these things you'll need to understand before you can really write any code.

Comment: Well I'm planning to use IMAP via laravel-imap to fetch the Emails and send them using SMTP via laravel. So laravel allows sending mails from all adresses within the server but the server has to allow aswell. I got it right?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much right. To fetch via IMAP you'll need each user's individual account credentials, for definite. To send via SMTP you might or might not need credentials...depends on the mailserver's setup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.